Omission of conjunction before a noun clause

Some said opportunity was required for success.

In this sentence, the conjunction 'that' is missing that introduces the noun clause. As a relative pronoun where 'that' acts as a dative case can be omitted like

The pen (that) I lost yesterday was expensive.

In this example, we have the choice to remove it. Is it ok to omit it before a noun clause, too?

The complementiser that is optional.  It introduces the declarative content clause

(that) opportunity was required for success

This is different from a relativiser introducing a relative clause like this one:

(that) I lost yesterday

You are right that the relativiser is optional.

It's optional in "[that] I lost yesterday" because the pen is not the subject of that clause. But "I threw away the pen that leaked on my shirt yesterday": "that" is not optional.

Thanks, @Andy Bonner.  Agreed.
